# DialogFragment is empty on usage (Android Studio)

Tags: android, dialogfragment

I moved a bunch of code over to being a `DialogFragment` in my program, and suddenly the Dialog is empty.

Tried to input other data like `Textviews` etc, but they also don't show, so I figured the issue is how i'm coupling the Layout file with the `DialogFragment` code.

DialogFragment Class:

```java
public class NewAccDialog extends DialogFragment {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View mView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.new_acc_dialog, null);
        builder.setTitle(getActivity().getString(R.string.overview_newacctitle_txt));

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        final Spinner accTypeSpinner = mView.findViewById(R.id.new_acc_spinner);
        accTypeSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        // onclicks removed

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

How I am using it in activity:

```java
public void createNewAcc(View v) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong("customerId", customerId);
        args.putParcelable("customerObject", customer);
        DialogFragment newAccDialog = new NewAccDialog();
        newAccDialog.setArguments(args);
        newAccDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "new_acc_dialog");

    }
```

No error messages are shown, but this is what my Dialog looks like:
[image: Screenshot of empty dialog][1]

Comment: You have Created `mView` but never used it . You should set it as a `ContentView` to dialog . Use `builder.setView(mView)`./

Comment: unbelieveable, thank you my friend

Answer (score 1):

please set your `mView` as content to your builder :

```
....
....
builder.setView(mView)
return builder.create();
```